# Catching 'Blocked loading mixed active content' CORS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, cors

In firefox, when javascript attempts to do a CORS request to a `http` server from a page that is hosted on `https`, it will throw an error:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content
```

I would like to catch these errors, but I can't figure out how. E.g.I tried something like this with jQuery:

```
try {
  $.get("http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/").fail(function(xhr, err){
    console.log("Server error:" + xhr.responseText);
  });
} catch(e){
  console.log(e.message);;
}
```

But buth `xhr.responseText` and `e.message` are empty strings (probably because `$.ajax` happens asynchronously). How can I catch the actual error message that says: *Blocked loading mixed active content...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot catch that exact message. It will only be logged to the console, but is not available to the user.

When using plain XHR, the `.open()` call would throw an exception that has `.result === 0x805e0006`. Also, `ex.toString()` will contain `nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"`.

jQuery, puts `ex.toString()` into the `.statusText` of the `jqXHR`, so you could do the following check for requests blocked due to mixed content:

```
xhr.statusText.indexOf('nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"') > -1
```

For the curious: `0x805e0006` should be [`NS_ERROR_CONTENT_BLOCKED`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e0776db3b102/content/base/src/nsXMLHttpRequest.cpp#l1619) (C++ macro value).

Comment: So what you are saying is that $.ajax call needs to be enhanced with a blocked field.

Comment: I found the line of code in jquery where xhr.open is called. In chrome, I am not getting an exception. Instead the exception is logged on xhr.send(), but xhr.statusText remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prevent the error in the first place by using a protocol relative URL:

```
$.get("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/")
```

uses either http or https, depending on your page context. public.opencpu.org supports both, so no problem there.

Comment: I know, but that's not the problem here. The user is to specify the URL.

Comment: @Jeroen That would have been helpful to mention in your question. Anyway, given arbitrary URIs, how do you ensure that the URI a) supports and b) allows CORS requests from you in the first place?

Comment: I don't, but that's being caught by the `fail` handler.